# AAD B2C | BI Reports

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can a B2C customer extract reports on user registration details? (I tried checking the sign-ins and audit reports on AAD; but couldn’t find anything)
From as simple as – who tried registering and what email ID was used; to complex reporting like login times, (social) provider used etc.?

Answer (score 0):

There is some reporting available under `Users and groups -> Sign-ins`.  The downloadable report (CSV file) has more details than what is displayed in the UI.

[image: activity report screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. This is admin level reporting. I am looking for end-user registration reporting for AAD B2C. E.g. If a new user self-registers on the portal, where are the logs on how many new users registered in last 24 hours? What social identity did they chose to create a new account in AAD B2C etc.?